# Dropzone.js post request in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I am not receiving any request at controller's uploadGallery method. Although, the post request is received correctly.

**gallery.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ url('file-upload') }}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="dz-message">
                                <h3>Drop images here or click to upload.</h3>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function (){

            Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
                paramName: "files",
                uploadMultiple:true,
                maxFilesize:6,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .jpeg",
                dictFallbackMessage:"Your browser does not support drag'n'drop file uploads.",
                dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
                dictFileTooBig:"Image is bigger than 6MB",

                accept: function(file, done) {
                    console.log("Uploaded");
                    done();
                },

                init:function() {
                /*  var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-all')
                        myAwesomeDropzone = this;

                    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(
                        myAwesomeDropzone.processQueue();
                    ));

                    this.on("addedfile", function(){
                        $('#submit-all').show();
                    });*/

                },  
                success: function(file,done){
                    console.log("All files done!");
                }
        }
        });
    </script>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/gallery', 'PagesController@Gallery');
Route::post('/file-upload', 'ImagesController@uploadImages');
```

**ImagesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function uploadImages(Image $request) {
        $images = request()->file('files');
        dd($images);
        return view('Gallery');
    }
}
```

Anything inside the uploadImages function is not running. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong type hinting in your `uploadImages()` function.

Change your `uploadImages()` from

```
public function uploadImages(Image $request)
```

to

```
public function uploadImages(Request $request)
```

Now you should be able to use `request()` to grab files.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public function uploadImages(Image $request) {
        $images = request()->file('files');
        dd($images);
        return view('Gallery');
    }
```

to and replace request() with $request since your using eloquent.

```
public function uploadImages(Request $request) {
        $images = $request->file('files');
        dd($images);
        return view('Gallery');
    }
```

For more detailed integration with laravel dropzone you can refer to this tutorial [Integrating Dropzone.js in Laravel 5 applications](http://anytch.com/integrating-dropzone-js-laravel-5-applications/)