# Dropzone autoProcessQueue: false not working

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to upload files on button click.

I have followed so much tutorials/questions like,
[Upload all files with a button](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button), [Dropzone.js post request in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012976/dropzone-js-post-request-in-laravel-5-4). But didn't get success.

This is my view file code,

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/candidate/file-upload') }}" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="dz-message">
        <h3>Drop images here or click to upload.</h3>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my JS file code (in document ready block),

```
//DropZone - Drag and drop file upload
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
    autoProcessQueue: false,

    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });
        // You might want to show the submit button only when 
        // files are dropped here:
        this.on("addedfile", function () {
            // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
        });
    }
};
```

But I think my this js file block is not executing. What should be the problem?

Comment: can you please brief details, what error you are getting in console.

Answer (score 5):

I fall at the same situation and found out that code:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { .. }
```

does nothink useful. Instead I use:

```
Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone").options.autoProcessQueue = false;
```

and after, when i need to queue i do:

```
Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone").processQueue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work:

`$(function(){
   Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {...}
}`

This worked:

`Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {...}`

...as long as it was executed **before** the DOM loaded.